# How to get a reference to a parent/super class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift you can create inheritance:

```
class A {

}

class B:A {

}
```

In this example `B` inherits from `A`. If I create a function within B is there a way I can get a reference to it's super class `A`? I was thinking it would be something like:

```
self.super
```

Or

```
self.super()
```

Or

```
self.parent
```

I tried all of these and none worked for me. Does anyone know how to get a reference to the super class?

Comment: What do you mean by "reference to its superclass"? What is it that you are really trying to do? You can access the inherited _implementation_ of some method — that's usually all anyone can ask for. What more do you want, in practical real life?

Comment: @matt I want a dynamic reference to the super class of any class to find out what the base class is. From there I assume I should be able to instantiate it or perform some sort of reflection on it.

Comment: Swift does not have introspection; that's deliberate. You can ask Cocoa to introspect for you, but again, you have not given a real example of what you want to do. If the idea is that you should do one thing if this is a B and another if this is an A, polymorphism takes care of that. For example, you can easily write a factory function that instantiates A or B depending on what we start with. Again, and for the last time, I ask you what you _really_ want to do.

Answer (score 4):

A pure Swift version of this, that works on Linux, but relies on a not-quite-official API is:

```
class A {}
class B: A {}

let superclass = Swift._getSuperclass (B.self)
print ("\(superclass)")
```

Thanks to [gwynne-raskind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1888760/gwynne-raskind) for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the Objective-C runtime, and then you can use `class_getSuperclass()`.

```
import ObjectiveC

class A {}

class B:A {
    func mySuper() -> AnyClass {
        return class_getSuperclass(self.dynamicType)
    }
}

B().mySuper() // A.Type
```

It is extremely unlikely that this is a good idea for anything other than debugging and logging. Even then, it is very un-Swiftlike, and you should deeply rethink your problem before pursuing it. Even subclassing like this is pretty un-Swiftlike. Protocols and extensions are almost always a better solution than inheritance in pure Swift (and without inheritance, there is no need to worry about superclasses).

Comment: What do you *want* to do with AnyClass? You can inspect it, send it messages, compare it to other classes, use it to specialize generic functions, etc. It's a Swift type.

Comment: As I said, you should avoid doing this in Swift. If you don't already have a specific reason to do this, don't. If you have a specific question about it, please open a new question. The OP asked how; he didn't explain his why.

Comment: You don't need import ObjectiveC
class A {}
let a = A.self
will give You the same

Comment: Correct, but not the superclass, which was the question. As you'll note, `B().mySuper()` returns `A.Type`, while `B.self` would return `B.Type`.

Answer (score 1):

Given class `A`:`B`, I was able to just call `self.superclass` within `B` after importing `ObjectiveC`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    var type: AnyClass { return A.self }
}

class B : A {
    override var type: AnyClass { return B.self }
    var superType: AnyClass { return super.type}
}

let type = B().type
let superType = B().superType
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Smiley {}

class EmojiSmiley: Smiley {}

func printSuperClassInfo<T>(_ value: T) {
    if let superClass: AnyClass =  class_getSuperclass(type(of: value) as? AnyClass) {
        print("superClass: ", superClass)
    }
}

let emojiSmiley = EmojiSmiley()
printSuperClassInfo(emojiSmiley)
```

output: **supertype:  Smiley**

Answer (score -1):

```
class A {
    func f() {
        print("A")
    }
}
class B : A {
    override func f() {
        print("B")
        super.f()
    }
}
let b = B()
b.f()
```